# Nested HTML5 Web SQL Query Issued after Entire For Loop Processed

Tags: javascript, sql, database, html

In this query listed below, my for loop is executing 4 values. In the first alert(id), it is alerting those 4 distinct values.  However, in the nested query, the alert statement is printing out the last id value only, 4x with different max(b.id) values.  I'm confused.  Does anyone know what may be happening?  Could a race condition be occurring?

My goal is to place an Ajax call in the nested query, which has input values based on both id and b.id.  I am currently doing this, but the value in the ajax call for the "id" is the same for all 4 different calls, which messes up the return data.  Thanks.

```
database.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT id, name from programs d', [], function (tx, results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    var id = results.rows.item(i)['id'];
                    var name = results.rows.item(i)['name'];
                        alert(id);

                    tx.executeSql('SELECT max(b.id) + 1 max from people b where b.sid = ?',
                        [id],
                        function (tx, results) {
                            lastRecord = results.rows.item(0)['max'];
                            alert(id + "last rec: " + name);
                        }
                    );
                }
            },
            function (event) { alert(event.message); });
```

Comment: Could you clarify?  Is your problem that the `[id]` used in the 2nd `tx.executeSql` is always the last one in the result set from the first query?

Comment: Yeah that's what is happening:
My problem is that the the query for the first nested query tx.executeSql('SELECT max...') is executing properly.  But in the scope of the alert under that, alert(id + "last rec: " + name) 
the id is only displayed as the last element.

Comment: This is causing a nested Ajax call in the first nested query to fail for 3/4 cases.

Comment: I did a console.log on the value of i within the first nested loop (select max...), and it shows that the value of i = 4.  (4 times).  I was expecting it to show, 0 1 2 3, but it appears that the outer for loop executes before the callback of the nested sql executes.

Comment: Yes, that is correct -- at the time that the 2nd executeSQL function finishes and triggers it's callback function, you've already stepped through the loop completely and i is = 4.  So it's going to be that forever -- to preserve the value you should pass it into your callback function as a parameter.

Comment: How can I pass it into my callback function?

Comment: Sorry -- my statement of how to preserve isn't right, though the cause is.

Comment: This is a closure discussion.  The short answer is that you need to declare a function that takes a parameter (id) that then returns a 2nd function that takes two parameters:  `tx, results`.   Inside that 2nd function you bind the parameter to the current value id (as passed via the parameter to the 1st function that creates the function on demand).  If no one else fills in this gap on this type of syntax, I'll come back and flesh this out.

Comment: Probably not the best way, but I used a few String objects to store the values of all the parameters passed in.  Then I used the very outer transaction callback to process the Ajax call by splitting the strings.  This seems to work for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, you to return a closed function to bind the parameter correctly.

A much simpler example is the following:

Running this produces 4 alerts, all showing 4:

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
    setTimeout( function() { alert(i)}, 1000);
}
```

Running this produces 4 alerts, showing 0/4, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4.

```
for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
    setTimeout(function(inneri) { 
        return( 
            function() { 
                alert(inneri + "/" + i);
            }
        );
    }(i), 1000);
}
```

where I've named `inneri` the value that was preserved upon closure.  Note that i, itself is still referring to the outer scope, and thus is 4 (which is what is true at time of execution, since that is the value of i when it dumps out of the for loop, as we're delaying the execution using `setTimeout()`.

The first case is a simpler version of what you're doing, whereas you want the second case.

Rewriting your js (and hoping I get all these ( and {'s in the right place :) ) gives:

```
database.db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT id, name from programs d', [], function (tx, results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                var id = results.rows.item(i)['id'];
                var name = results.rows.item(i)['name'];
                alert(id);

                tx.executeSql('SELECT max(b.id) + 1 max from people b where b.sid = ?',
                    [id],
                    function(innerId) { 
                       return (
                          function (tx, results) {
                                lastRecord = results.rows.item(0)['max'];
                                alert(innerId + "last rec: " + name);
                          }
                       );
                    }(id) //be careful to avoid the ";" here!
                );
            }
        },
        function (event) { alert(event.message); 
    });
```

Where I have inserted:

```
 function(innerId) { 
    return (
         function (tx, results) {
             lastRecord = results.rows.item(0)['max'];
             alert(innerId + "last rec: " + name);
         }
    );
 }(id)
```

in.  This function is called immediately via the `(id)` and returns a function that takes `tx` and `results` as arguments and does the appropriate action.

I have checked braces/parenthesis, but don't have a direct way to verify that I didn't make any typos.